# Syncing my github forked repository with the upstream and keeping my changes

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to sync my github forked repository with the original one. I've followed the instructions on the [github's page](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork). But when I try to merge my own master branch with upstream's, it says:

```
$ git merge upstream/master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    ... a list of files ...
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

It's in the case that when I `git commit` it says `nothing to commit (working directory clean)`!

What am I missing?

Comment: what is the output of `git status` ?

Comment: `# On branch master \n nothing to commit (working directory clean)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your line endings:
https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings

Comment: Thanks, right now I've done `git config --global core.autocrlf input` but nothing changed. Am I supposed to do anything more?

Comment: Did you https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings#re-normalizing-a-repository ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it was line ending or just `git reset --hard` but it worked. Thanks.